# Pull with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, pull

I have project1 and project2. I would like to have a version in project1 to project2. So i make pull and merge two project with Netbeans. Is it possible?
How to pull another project with netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but to pull a project, all you have to do is add the remote location and do a pull.

1. have a connection set up already to your remote1
2. right click on your project and select git>remote>pull...
3. enter in the address to project2.
4. then pull, selecting project 2 in "specify git repository location:"
5. The pull command automatically runs "git merge", so you will be prompted with a conflict resolution dialogue if there are conflicts.

It is important to know that using pull... is not the recommended way to do things, but I am a beginner at git and it works well enough for me and my simple projects. If you want to find out the technicalities of git pull vs git fetch, then you can find lots of answers on here.

Comment: My project is not on git but on another server. I have a project in netbeans. It was this project in netbeans that I would merge with the project on the server.